Arrowhead line animation
I want to make an arrow-marked path animation. I made an arrow, and I know the path animation method, but I have a problem. I want the arrow to follow a visible path to the target after leaving the starting point. I couldn't find a way to do this.
I did it with Grease Pencil, but I didn't like this method. I also tried the object-following-path method. But I wasn't satisfied with these. How can I make an arrow movement on a plane/map in 3D as seen in the image?



Create a segment (1), and its start and end tips (2 and 3):

Give it an Array modifier with object 2 and 3 as Cap Start and Cap End:

Give it a Curve modifier:

Animate the Offset value of the Array to make the arrow get longer:


I am doing all of them but the tip of the arrow and the cover part (2 and 3) do not fit into the front and back of cube number 1. They fit sideways. How can I place pieces number 2 and 3 neatly in front and back of cube number 1?

Select the front object, switch to Edit mode, move the mesh so that it sticks to the segment

''Fixed Count'' didn't respond. So i tired ''fit curve'' and this time it goes straight. It doesn't follow the road.

could you please share your file?
